# Why is the column not populating

Tags: sql, oracle

I am really stumped here. I have all the values I need showing up in my table and this code was provided by the lab, but for some reason the `rental_item_price` column just won't populate. If it is left null then I have to add junk code so that I can add a restraint to the column of `NOT NULL`. Any ideas why this code is not working?

```
UPDATE   rental_item ri
SET      rental_item_price =
      (SELECT   p.amount
       FROM     price p INNER JOIN common_lookup cl1
       ON       p.price_type = cl1.common_lookup_id CROSS JOIN rental r
                CROSS JOIN common_lookup cl2 
       WHERE    p.item_id = ri.item_id AND ri.rental_id = r.rental_id
       AND      ri.rental_item_type = cl2.common_lookup_id
       AND      cl1.common_lookup_code = cl2.common_lookup_code
       AND      r.check_out_date
                  BETWEEN p.start_date AND NVL(p.end_date, TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 1);
```

I may have asked the wrong question or put too much thought into. The error I am receiving is this

```
 UPDATE   rental_item ri
 ERROR at line 1
 ORA-00921: unexpected end of SQL command
```

Comment: You need to provide us data for all the used tables on which it fails ([mcve]).

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. I'm getting an ora-00921 error at line 1 if that helps.

Comment: And what documentation says about ORA-00921?

Comment: First of all you should get your joins straight. A cross join is a join where you join a table without any criteria (so as to generate all possible combinations such as all products x all stores, no matter whether the product is offered in the store). You pretend to `CROSS JOIN r` and `CROSS JOIN cl2`, but then you have `cl1.common_lookup_code = cl2.common_lookup_code` and `r.check_out_date BETWEEN p.start_date ...`. So the joins become inner joins. Re-write this and maybe this helps you find semantic errors, if any. Your syntax error is that you are missing the closing parenthesis at the end.

Comment: It is difficult to see what are you trying to achieve with your query. It is clearly missing a closing bracket as you can see in answer, but is fixing this going to get you results you want? Hard to say. Follow @ThorstenKettner advice and get you join right first.

Comment: You need to get a text editor or IDE which does **bracket matching**. If you had been using such a tool then you would have found your syntax error immediately.

Comment: APC thank you for the recommendation. I am using gedit on an ssh tunnel into my schools linux lab. Still learning a lot of the different ways to get files and work on things. @ThorstenKettner Thank you for the info and teaching. I only kind of follow the code itself as it was written by the class instructor for students to plug in. I'm still trying to wrap my head around some of the terminology and what not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You open the select statement with a (, but never close it. Add a ) at the end.

```
UPDATE   rental_item ri
SET      rental_item_price =
      (SELECT   p.amount
       FROM     price p INNER JOIN common_lookup cl1
       ON       p.price_type = cl1.common_lookup_id CROSS JOIN rental r
                CROSS JOIN common_lookup cl2 
       WHERE    p.item_id = ri.item_id AND ri.rental_id = r.rental_id
       AND      ri.rental_item_type = cl2.common_lookup_id
       AND      cl1.common_lookup_code = cl2.common_lookup_code
       AND      r.check_out_date
                  BETWEEN p.start_date AND NVL(p.end_date, TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 1))
```